# How to get first value of the key from the file?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the first value of the key but it is printing two values. Can anyone please suggest me.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileReader(configFilePath));

String appName = props.getProperty("app","env");
System.out.println("AppName:"+appName);
```

I need to print only "abc" as applications and environment as "ab".Please suggest.

Comment: Your problem is that `getProperty` will put in your `appName`  `abc,tds`. You could split this string using something like: `String[] appNameSplit = appName.split(",");`

Comment: And then you can use `appNameSplit[0]` to access `abc`

Comment: @David Buzatu Thanks...How can I get for environment.Can u pls suggest

Comment: *Caution:* `props.getProperty("application","environment")` does not do what you think it does.  You’re supplying a default value.  See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), you can see that `props.getProperty(String propertyName)` will get your value for the `propertyName` key. What you did was you used `props.getProperty(String propertyName, String defaultValue)`, which won't get `environment` unless `applications` is not found.

I will assume you want both of them. For this, you should do the following:

```
String appName = props.getProperty("applications");
String[] appNameSplitted = appName.split(","); // split after comma
// to get 'abc', do
String firstAppName = appNameSplitted[0];
// to get 'tds' do
String secondAppName = appNameSplitted[1];
```

The same goes for `environment`:

```
String envName = props.getProperty("environment");
String[] envNameSplitted = envName.split(","); // split after comma
// to get 'ab', do
String firstEnvName = envNameSplitted[0];
// to get 'bc' do
String secondEnvName = envNameSplitted[1];
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, if you want now to get `abc.csv` from what you have, I suggest you use `StringBuilder` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html))

Basically, you want to take your splitted string and append to it the `.csv` string. This is done as follows:

```
StringBuilder file1 = new StringBuilder();
file1.append(appNameSplitted[0])
     .append(".csv");
// the same goes for all the other options
// to get the string value of file1, use
file1.toString(); // this is now "abc.csv"
```

For the last comment, simply do:

```
StringBuilder file2 = new StringBuilder();
file2.append(appNameSplitted[1])
     .append("-")
     .append(envNameSplitted[1])
     .append(".csv");
```

Comment: Thanks How i need to add "appName.csv " for the output we get. I need to get the file name using that applicateion name which is .csv.Could you please suggest

Comment: Could you please explain a little better? I can't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to create a `.csv` file using the name from the `applications` property?

Comment: Like i need to add the extension as appNameSplitted[1].csv for application property and [appNameSplitted[1]-envNameSplitted[1]].csv

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I hope its what you asked for

Comment: Can we do same for this also [appNameSplitted[1]-envNameSplitted[1]].csv

Comment: Of course. If you want to add any new character, simply use `.append(yourString)` to append it to the `StringBuilder` variable

Comment: Thanks I have another question...But not able post in this

Comment: You should post another question. If my answer was good for this question, you can accept it

Comment: can you please check my new question and please can you help on that tooo.....it will very thankful

Comment: i want to merge the file of abc.csv as it is String Builder i could not pass it in file files[1] = new File(abc.csv variable); it is asking me to change to String.How can i do it.Please suggest

Comment: I already told you. You have your `StringBuilder` variable (say `file1`). You pass that to `new File(file1.toString());`. Please try to understand the programming language you are using and don't expect StackOverflow to teach you everything you need